# Tensorflow tf.data.Dataset interleave() returns Unexpected result

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, interleave

I was following some another example from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67332793/tensorflow-dataset-interleave-from-generator-throws-invalidargumenterror) which is about the `tf.data.Dataset.interleave()` method.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras

def do_range(i):
    for j in tf.range(i):
        yield j

ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(10).interleave(
    lambda ind: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(do_range, args=(ind,), output_types=tf.int64))
```

I tried to understand this example, so I started with the `range(3)`, `range(4)`, ..., and so on.
For example,

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(3).interleave(
    lambda ind: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(do_range, args=(ind,), output_types=tf.int64))
res = [x for x in ds.as_numpy_iterator()]
# This returns [0, 0, 1]
```

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(4).interleave(
    lambda ind: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(do_range, args=(ind,), output_types=tf.int64))
res = [x for x in ds.as_numpy_iterator()]
# This returns [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
```

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(5).interleave(
    lambda ind: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(do_range, args=(ind,), output_types=tf.int64))
res = [x for x in ds.as_numpy_iterator()]
# This returns [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

Until `range(9)`, it returns the dataset I expected. 
But from `range(10)`, it doesn't return the dataset I expected.

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(10).interleave(
    lambda ind: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(do_range, args=(ind,), output_types=tf.int64))
res = [x for x in ds.as_numpy_iterator()]
# This returns [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 6, 6, 5, 7, 6, 7, 8]
# Notice that 0s, 1s, 2s are not gathered..
```

What is going on here? Isn't this should be `[0, ..., 0, 1, ..., 1, 2, ..., 2, ..., 8]` ?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this on TF 2.7. Which version you are using?

Comment: @Frightera TF 2.5..that's strange..

Comment: @Frightera I checked it again but still got the same result. Did you get what I expected for the case of `tf.data.Dataset.range(10)...`?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: @AloneTogether Analgous to previous examples, output for `tf.data.Dataset.range(10).interleave(...)` should be `[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, ..., 1, 2, ..., 2, ..., 3, ..., 3, 4, ..., 4, 5, ..., 8]`. In words, Nine 0s, Eight 1s, Seven 2s, Six 3s, ..., One 8.

Comment: I tested this on Colab, my results were different than yours. They were not ordered, so I can not reproduce when it is `range(5)` etc. The results that I've obtained were like your last example.

Comment: @Frightera It's really weird. I restarted my jupyter and rerun the whole code, still got the same results as above. But when I rerun the code with Colab, I got completely different results. Haha

Comment: Probably it has something to do with `from_generator` not `interleave` but I don't know the internal details of `from_generator`. According to my experience it is little bit problematic I think :(